# Can't delete a file from folder

Tags: c#, wpf

How does it fix? I checked all good sites, and this is the last way to delete, but it's not working. There is my code, I've no idea, why it's not working, just pops up "else" line.

```
public Task DownloadWithStream(FileInfo info)
        {
            return Task.Run(() =>
            {
                using (Stream stream = info.client.OpenRead(info.FileName))
                {
                    info.MaxProgress = Convert.ToInt64(info.client.ResponseHeaders["Content-Length"]) / 1024 / 1024;
                    using (FileStream fs = File.Create($@"{info.FolderName}/{Path.GetFileName(info.FileName)}"))
                    {
                        int len = 0;
                        do
                        {
                            info.ResetEvent.WaitOne();
                            byte[] buff = new byte[1024];
                            len = stream.Read(buff, 0, buff.Length);
                            fs.Write(buff, 0, len);
                            info.Progress += len / (double)1024 / (double)1024;
                        }
                        while (len > 0);
                    }
                }
            });
        }

private void btnRename_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
string filePath = tbTo.Text;
if (File.Exists(filePath))
{
File.Delete(filePath);
//lbOutput.SelectedItems.Remove(lbOutput.SelectedItems);
MessageBox.Show("Folder Deleted");
}
else
{
MessageBox.Show("Folder in not exists");
}
}
```

Comment: Consider adding the file and folder name to your message. It's not unusual to have messed up the name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't execute IO operations like reading/writing file or download streams on a background thread. Instead use the provided async API of `FileStream` or `Stream` wrappers like `StreamWriter`/`StreamReader`:

```
using var fileStream = File.OpenWrite(filePath);

// StreamReader/StreamWriter decorates any Stream
using var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(fileStream);

// Write to the underlying stream asynchronously.
// Far better perfomance then executing synchronous IO operations on a background thread (Task.Run)
await streamWriter.WriteAsync("Some text");
```

To handle files that are selected by the user *always* avoid a plain `TextBox` or text input in general. This is error prone and provides a bad user experience. It's more conveniet to use a file picker dialog. Such a dialog avoids errors due to typing errors or invalid file paths like nonexistent files.

```
private void DeleteFile_OnButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
  var filePickerDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
  if (filePickerDialog.ShowDialog() == true)
  {
    string fileToDelete = filePickerDialog.FileName;
    File.Delete(fileToDelete);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. You helped me with this, but I have one more question. I need to delete a file from ListBox, but nothing has worked.

Comment: What do you mean, can you explain this a little bit more? A ListBox does not contain files. Do you mean filename? You must provide more details about how you set it up. Usually you remove items from a ListBox by removing it from the ItemsSource or from the source collection that binds to the ItemsSource to be precise.